# Sort DOM elements in array

Tags: javascript, dom

I have an array which tracks the movement of elements on the DOM. Therefore, at any point, the DOM (represented by the variable `components`) might look as follow due to intermittent changes by the user:

```
["app-builder-placeholder", 
 "app-builder-placeholder", 
 "app-builder-footer", 
 "app-builder-navbar", 
 "app-builder-placeholder"] 

["app-builder-placeholder", 
 "app-builder-placeholder", 
 "app-builder-navbar", 
 "app-builder-footer", 
 "app-builder-placeholder"]

["app-builder-placeholder", 
 "app-builder-placeholder", 
 "app-builder-footer", 
 "app-builder-navbar", 
 "app-builder-placeholder"]

["app-builder-navbar", 
 "app-builder-placeholder",
 "app-builder-placeholder", 
 "app-builder-footer", 
 "app-builder-placeholder"]
```

I would re-sort the array to guarantee the following:
- `app-builder-placeholder` item comes before/after a "non" `app-builder-xxx` item
- two `app-builder-placeholder` items cannot follow each other

So in effect, the above should really look like this:

```
["app-builder-placeholder",
 "app-builder-navbar",
 "app-builder-placeholder",
 "app-builder-footer",
 "app-builder-placeholder"]
```

or

```
["app-builder-placeholder",
 "app-builder-footer",
 "app-builder-placeholder",
 "app-builder-navbar",
 "app-builder-placeholder"]
```

as these are the only two possible ways it can be sorted.

My current code which tracks the update of the DOM is as follows. How would I extend it so that the array is sanitised accordingly. In a situation where the criteria is not met, placeholder items can be created on the spot before and after the non placeholder items so that the array is re-crafted to fit the criteria.

```
this.options = {
  onUpdate: function (e: any) {
    let components = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < e.target.children.length; i++) {
      components.push(e.target.children[i].children[0].children[0].localName)
    }
    console.log(components);
  }
};
```

Comment: What's the desired behavior if an element doesn't meet the criteria?

Comment: The placeholder items should be added before and after the non placeholder items so that the array is recrafted to fit the criteria. It doesn't need to make specific use of the placeholders within the array as there exists, it would be perfectly fine to create the array with the old placeholders cancelled out and new ones added in the correct order. I guess my challenge at the moment is figuring out the optimal way to do this.

Comment: so you want to sort your array .?

Comment: with the placeholder conditions in place, but not the order of the items changed

Comment: so there is *always* a placeholder at the front and back and between each element?

Comment: Yes, but there should never be two placeholders following each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way you could do it using plenty of array helpers:

```
let counter = components.length, placeholderName = "app-builder-placeholder";
//calculate new array size with required number of placeholders
let newLength = components.filter(c => c != placeholderName).length*2+1;

//remove excess placeholders
while(newLength > components.length)
  components.splice(components.lastIndexOf(placeholderName), 1);

//add placeholders if needed
components.length = newLength;
components.fill(placeholderName,counter);

//iterate and move placeholders to proper locations, preserving order
for(let i = 0, counter = 0; i < components.length; i++)
  if(components[i] == placeholderName)
    components.splice((counter++)*2, 0, components.splice(i, 1)[0]);
```

Comment: There's a bug in this that I can't figure out.